# Problems with ImageTk (from Anaconda distribution)

Tags: image, tkinter, anaconda

I switched to Anaconda recently (yesterday...) and now I have a problem with ImageTk.PhotoImage:

```
>>> im = Image.open(fn) # fn is a png image
>>> im
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=411x484 at
0x10F9D4750>
>>> imtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
Exception AttributeError: "'PhotoImage' object has no attribute
'_PhotoImage__photo'" in <bound method PhotoImage.__del__ of
<PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage object at 0x10f9d45d0>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/eduardomartinez/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 112, in __init__
  self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
  File "/Users/eduardomartinez/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3367, in __init__
  Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/Users/eduardomartinez/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3304, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError, 'Too early to create image'
RuntimeError: Too early to create image
```

This used to work. Any clue?

Comment: This is telling you that you have to create the root window first.

Comment: Indeed! That fixed it.